# Capture the output of a process in Julia

Tags: pipe, julia, ipc, stdout

I want to run a process and capture its output. According [the documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/), method `open(command, stdio=devnull; write::Bool = false, read::Bool = !write)` should return a tuple `(stream,process)`. But when running

```
typeof(open(`ls`))
```

the output is `Base.Process`. So only the process is returned, no stream.

Am I misunderstanding the documentation? How do I start a process and somehow capture its output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an [error in the documentation](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/24649) (the function was changed between 0.6 and 1.0, but the docs were not updated).

You can just call any "reading" function, such as `read`, `eachline` or `readlines` on the process, or even on the command itself, e.g.

```
readlines(open(`ls`))
readlines(`ls`)
```

Comment: I thinks it is very helpful to newcomers to Julia, like me, to  explicitly point out when the documentation is in error.  Thanks Simon.